# Communication between separated vuex stores

Tags: vue-component, vuex, vue.js

Imagine invoice. It has products. Each product should have computed property 'total' (quantity * price). Total of invoice is also computed property (sum of all products totals). How could I solve this? I tried to create 'products' array attribute in store state, and push there separated product stores. But in strict mode my browser crashed, so probably this isn't a right way :)

Comment: Could you add some code?

Comment: Could you please post your solution?

Comment: Instead pushing stores, I'v used plain object with getters/setters. For example: 

`get total() { return this.quantity * this.price; }`

In this way i'm able to use invoice.total, to get calculated attribute.